# Tomcat java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file

Tags: maven, tomcat, netbeans, jar

I am getting the following error from Tomcat on my Maven project:

```
Jul 25, 2014 4:59:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/SomePRJ] is completed
Jul 25, 2014 5:00:00 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader modified
INFO:     Additional JARs have been added : 'jta-1.0.1B.jar'
Jul 25, 2014 5:00:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading Context with name [/SomePRJ] has started
Jul 25, 2014 5:00:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig tldScanJar
WARNING: Failed to process JAR [jar:jndi:/localhost/SomePRJ/WEB-INF/lib/jta-1.0.1B.jar!/null] for TLD files
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file

at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile$1.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.retrieve(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.tldScanJar(TldConfig.java:507)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.access$100(TldConfig.java:59)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig$TldJarScannerCallback.scan(TldConfig.java:332)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.process(StandardJarScanner.java:234)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:159)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.execute(TldConfig.java:306)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.lifecycleEvent(TldConfig.java:585)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:89)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5081)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:3832)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:424)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1205)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1391)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1401)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1401)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1380)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Suppressed: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Users\AYSE\apache-tomcat-7.0.40\temp\jar_cache4346520121091241214.tmp

    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.delete(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.file.Files.delete(Unknown Source)
    ... 27 more
```

The project is building fine with no errors, with a warning on the project WAR file-- if this is any significant.

I'm running it all on NetBeans, it's a "Maven Webapp".

I tried different versions of `jta-1.0.1B.jar` and got the same thing.

What is missing???

Note: I saw [JBoss5: Cannot deploy due to java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646322/jboss5-cannot-deploy-due-to-java-util-zip-zipexception-error-in-opening-zip-fi), [java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325202/java-util-zip-zipexception-error-in-opening-zip-file), [java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file ,tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24799533/java-util-zip-zipexception-error-in-opening-zip-file-tomcat) and some other discussions. 
TIA.

Comment: Are you running out of disk space? Directory permission problems? For some reason the temp file it thinks it has created does not exist.

Comment: @JimGarrison turned out to be that - yes. My disk space shd be alright but the RAM was short. Might be something with caching. worked on the other machine.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56606626/1840774