# Can't load jar - "zip file is empty"

Tags: java, jar, jboss, bouncycastle, jar-signing

My application is deployed inside a JBoss6 server which contains the latest BC implementation, bcprov-jdk15on-151.jar placed in the lib folder of the server installation. 
When trying to run the following piece of code:

```
    if (java.security.Security.getProvider("BC") == null)
    {
        java.security.Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
    }
    try
    {
        this.keyFac = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES", "BC");
    }
    catch (NoSuchProviderException ex)
    {
        logger.warn("Cipher initializing failed", ex);
    }
```

I run into the NoSuchProvider exception, that looks the following:

```
    2014-10-22 17:26:37,670 WARN  pool-81-thread-10 [ngnms.collector.q1adapter.NeraCrypt:] Cipher initializing failed: java.security.NoSuchProviderException: JCE cannot authenticate the provider BC
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.getInstance(JceSecurity.java:101)
    at javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(SecretKeyFactory.java:203)
    at no.nera.networks.ngnms.collector.q1adapter.NeraCrypt.<init>(NeraCrypt.java:75)
    at no.nera.networks.ngnms.collector.q1adapter.NeraCrypt.getInstance(NeraCrypt.java:108)
    at no.nera.networks.ngnms.collector.q1adapter.msgencode.clil.CLILSecurityLogonEncoder.encode(CLILSecurityLogonEncoder.java:76)
    at no.nera.networks.ngnms.collector.q1adapter.msgencode.Q1EncoderFactory.EncodeMessage(Q1EncoderFactory.java:138)
    at no.nera.networks.ngnms.collector.ejb.q1adapter.Q1CommandBean.setElementToManagedState(Q1CommandBean.java:329)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeTarget(MethodInvocation.java:122)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:111)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.container.ContainerMethodInvocationWrapper.invokeNext(ContainerMethodInvocationWrapper.java:72)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InterceptorSequencer.invoke(InterceptorSequencer.java:76)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InterceptorSequencer.aroundInvoke(InterceptorSequencer.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor479.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.aop.advice.PerJoinpointAdvice.invoke(PerJoinpointAdvice.java:174)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor.fillMethod(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:74)
    at org.jboss.aop.advice.org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor_z_fillMethod_1654429238.invoke(InvocationContextInterceptor_z_fillMethod_1654429238.java)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor.setup(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.jboss.aop.advice.org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor_z_setup_1654429238.invoke(InvocationContextInterceptor_z_setup_1654429238.java)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.async.impl.interceptor.AsynchronousServerInterceptor.invoke(AsynchronousServerInterceptor.java:128)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.connectionmanager.CachedConnectionInterceptor.invoke(CachedConnectionInterceptor.java:62)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.entity.TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.invoke(TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.java:56)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.AllowedOperationsInterceptor.invoke(AllowedOperationsInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.tx.NullInterceptor.invoke(NullInterceptor.java:42)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessInstanceInterceptor.invoke(StatelessInstanceInterceptor.java:68)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.core.context.SessionInvocationContextAdapter.proceed(SessionInvocationContextAdapter.java:95)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.tx2.impl.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:223)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.tx2.impl.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:353)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.tx2.impl.CMTTxInterceptor.invoke(CMTTxInterceptor.java:209)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.tx2.aop.CMTTxInterceptorWrapper.invoke(CMTTxInterceptorWrapper.java:52)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPropagationInterceptor.invoke(TxPropagationInterceptor.java:76)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.tx.NullInterceptor.invoke(NullInterceptor.java:42)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.security.Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptorv2.invoke(Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptorv2.java:182)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.ENCPropagationInterceptor.invoke(ENCPropagationInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.BlockContainerShutdownInterceptor.invoke(BlockContainerShutdownInterceptor.java:67)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.core.context.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.invoke(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.aspects.currentinvocation.CurrentInvocationInterceptor.invoke(CurrentInvocationInterceptor.java:67)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptor.EJB3TCCLInterceptor.invoke(EJB3TCCLInterceptor.java:86)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.session.SessionSpecContainer.invoke(SessionSpecContainer.java:333)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.session.SessionSpecContainer.invoke(SessionSpecContainer.java:390)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor480.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.impl.handler.session.SessionLocalProxyInvocationHandler$LocalContainerInvocation.invokeTarget(SessionLocalProxyInvocationHandler.java:184)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:111)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.async.impl.interceptor.AsynchronousClientInterceptor.invoke(AsynchronousClientInterceptor.java:143)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.impl.handler.session.SessionLocalProxyInvocationHandler$LocalInvokableContextHandler.invoke(SessionLocalProxyInvocationHandler.java:159)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy459.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.impl.handler.session.SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.invoke(SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.java:185)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy320.setElementToManagedState(Unknown Source)
    at no.nera.networks.ngnms.mediator.ejbmediator.MediatorServiceBean.setManagedState(MediatorServiceBean.java:790)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeTarget(MethodInvocation.java:122)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:111)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.container.ContainerMethodInvocationWrapper.invokeNext(ContainerMethodInvocationWrapper.java:72)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InterceptorSequencer.invoke(InterceptorSequencer.java:76)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InterceptorSequencer.aroundInvoke(InterceptorSequencer.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor479.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.aop.advice.PerJoinpointAdvice.invoke(PerJoinpointAdvice.java:174)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor.fillMethod(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:74)
    at org.jboss.aop.advice.org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor_z_fillMethod_1654429238.invoke(InvocationContextInterceptor_z_fillMethod_1654429238.java)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor.setup(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.jboss.aop.advice.org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor_z_setup_1654429238.invoke(InvocationContextInterceptor_z_setup_1654429238.java)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.async.impl.interceptor.AsynchronousServerInterceptor.invoke(AsynchronousServerInterceptor.java:128)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.connectionmanager.CachedConnectionInterceptor.invoke(CachedConnectionInterceptor.java:62)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.entity.TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.invoke(TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.java:56)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.AllowedOperationsInterceptor.invoke(AllowedOperationsInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.tx.NullInterceptor.invoke(NullInterceptor.java:42)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessInstanceInterceptor.invoke(StatelessInstanceInterceptor.java:68)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.core.context.SessionInvocationContextAdapter.proceed(SessionInvocationContextAdapter.java:95)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.tx2.impl.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:223)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.tx2.impl.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:353)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.tx2.impl.CMTTxInterceptor.invoke(CMTTxInterceptor.java:209)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.tx2.aop.CMTTxInterceptorWrapper.invoke(CMTTxInterceptorWrapper.java:52)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPropagationInterceptor.invoke(TxPropagationInterceptor.java:76)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.tx.NullInterceptor.invoke(NullInterceptor.java:42)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.security.Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptorv2.invoke(Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptorv2.java:182)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.ENCPropagationInterceptor.invoke(ENCPropagationInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.BlockContainerShutdownInterceptor.invoke(BlockContainerShutdownInterceptor.java:67)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.core.context.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.invoke(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.aspects.currentinvocation.CurrentInvocationInterceptor.invoke(CurrentInvocationInterceptor.java:67)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptor.EJB3TCCLInterceptor.invoke(EJB3TCCLInterceptor.java:86)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.session.SessionSpecContainer.invoke(SessionSpecContainer.java:333)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.session.SessionSpecContainer.invoke(SessionSpecContainer.java:390)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor480.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.impl.handler.session.SessionLocalProxyInvocationHandler$LocalContainerInvocation.invokeTarget(SessionLocalProxyInvocationHandler.java:184)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:111)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.async.impl.interceptor.AsynchronousClientInterceptor.invoke(AsynchronousClientInterceptor.java:143)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.impl.handler.session.SessionLocalProxyInvocationHandler$LocalInvokableContextHandler.invoke(SessionLocalProxyInvocationHandler.java:159)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy459.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.impl.handler.session.SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.invoke(SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.java:185)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy220.setManagedState(Unknown Source)
    at no.nera.networks.ngnms.core.mrs.TopologyEventPublisher$1.runTransacted(TopologyEventPublisher.java:462)
    at no.nera.networks.ngnms.core.scheduler.QueuedTransRunnable.runInternal(QueuedTransRunnable.java:111)
    at no.nera.networks.ngnms.core.scheduler.QueuedTransRunnable.run(QueuedTransRunnable.java:77)
    at no.nera.networks.ngnms.core.scheduler.SchedulerImpl$QueuedRunnableWrapper.run(SchedulerImpl.java:75)
    at com.ceragon.nms.server.common.scheduler.impl.QueuedRunWrapper.run(QueuedRunWrapper.java:102)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Cannot verify jar:vfs:/C:/NetMaster/Server/JBoss-4.2.3/server/netmaster/lib/bcprov-jdk15on-151.jar/!/
    at javax.crypto.JarVerifier.verifySingleJar(JarVerifier.java:406)
    at javax.crypto.JarVerifier.verifyJars(JarVerifier.java:322)
    at javax.crypto.JarVerifier.verify(JarVerifier.java:250)
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.verifyProviderJar(JceSecurity.java:161)
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.getVerificationResult(JceSecurity.java:187)
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.getInstance(JceSecurity.java:98)
    ... 153 more
Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.util.zip.ZipException: zip file is empty
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.crypto.JarVerifier.verifySingleJar(JarVerifier.java:384)
    ... 158 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: zip file is empty
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.retrieve(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
    at javax.crypto.JarVerifier$2.run(JarVerifier.java:399)
    ... 160 more
    Suppressed: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\NetMaster\Server\JBoss-4.2.3\server\netmaster\tmp\jar_cache8677903837427534429.tmp
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.delete(Unknown Source)
        at java.nio.file.Files.delete(Unknown Source)
        ... 169 more
```

JBoss seems not to succeed in opening the JAR for verification in the tmp directory.
I've done multiple tests, such as:
- verify the jar manually in a separate main class
- create a file in the tmp directory and open it, in the JBoss application code
- change the default tmp directory (java.io.tmpdir)

All of these succeeded and I've run out of ideas for this issue.

I noticed that this problem is quite rare, has occured a couple of times on the Internet and not only for JBoss apps:

https://developer.jboss.org/message/857086 - same issue
http://markmail.org/thread/j46247s7wjamgebt - same issue
[Tomcat java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24964706/tomcat-java-util-zip-zipexception-error-in-opening-zip-file) - tomcat

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about jboss 6 but it works in jboss 7.1 if you add this in jboss-deployment-structure.xml:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>  
   <deployment>  
      <resources>  
         <resource-root path="WEB-INF/lib/bcprov-jdk15on-151.jar" use-physical-code-source="true"/>  
      </resources>  
   </deployment>  
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

More infos here: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/175395

Answer (score 0):

In server standalone.xml file add below global module under `<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:4.0">`

```
<global-modules>
    <module name="org.bouncycastle" slot="main"/>
</global-modules>
```