# Tomcat 8 Warning - unable to scan JAR

Tags: java, tomcat

I get a weird warning

```
28-Nov-2017 14:34:23.608 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan 
Failed to scan 
[file:/home/user/apache-tomcat-8.5.6/lib/._catalina-ha.jar] from classloader 
hierarchy
 java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file


at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:220)
at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:150)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:130)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFileUrlJar.<init>(JarFileUrlJar.java:60)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFactory.newInstance(JarFactory.java:48)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.process(Stan...
```

I see these files are present. but it has some weird content when i open it with VIM (incluses Mac OSX word) But I use CentOS.

Is there some problem with my Tomcat? How do I fix this?

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24799533/java-util-zip-zipexception-error-in-opening-zip-file-tomcat can help?

Comment: @RoiG how about I try keeping these files out of the lib folder? Does tomcat load all the jars in lib folder on deployment?